# For laravel application add cron jobs in linux server

Tags: laravel-5, cron

**Hi**
In laravel I have done scheduling the commands, I Have doubt on this step.

`*** * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1**`.

path means which path(laravel application path)?.

`*** * * * * php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1**`.

is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full path to where your artisan file is. If you look in your Laravel root directory, you should find that it is there - so, simply put, the path to that directory as a whole. If your Laravel installation, in your case, resides in `/var/www/html/laravel`, then the path is correct.

Comment: I founded artisan file. **schedule:run**  means it runs all schedules or mention particular schedule?.     I have schedule like registerExceptions is my schedule   php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan registerExceptions:run is this right?

Comment: schedule:run will run any schedule that is scheduled to be run at that point in time. If you wish to run only a specific task, schedule it to run at the intervals you need it to. Laravel has a minutely cron because it handles its own scheduling.

Comment: Thank you CmdrSharp